# Generating a pseudo-random number and a letter with no repetitions

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate randomly 5 strings that will look like this "A1, B3, C7, D2, I8" and with no repetitions. The end result should be a working function that gives me a letter and a number easy to confront.
Here's the function I've made, by the way the problem with this function is that 
it gives me only numbers.

```
using namespace std;

char letters[]= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L'};
int Num[11];
char pGuess[10];
string generateSetOfNumbers()
{
    int G = rand() % 10;
    int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
    char lOut = letters[G];
    int Max = 5;
    int Min = 0;
    string culo =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
    {
        int G = rand() % 10;
        int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
        char lOut = letters[G];
        int Max = 5;
        int Min = 0;
        string culo1 =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
        return culo1;
    }
    {
        int G = rand() % 10;
        int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
        char lOut = letters[G];
        int Max = 5;
        int Min = 0;
        string culo2 =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
        return culo2;
    }
    {
        int G = rand() % 10;
        int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
        char lOut = letters[G];
        int Max = 5;
        int Min = 0;
        string culo3 =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
        return culo3;
    }
    {
        int G = rand() % 10;
        int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
        char lOut = letters[G];
        int Max = 5;
        int Min = 0;
        string culo4 =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
        return culo4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to acheive what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

// build an array of strings A1-9 to I1-9
// then shuffle it randomly (like a deck of cards)
std::vector<std::string> make_candidates()
{
    // this builds the array
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // for each number 1 to 9...
    for(int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        // for each letter A to I...
        for(char c = 'A' ; c < 'J' ; ++c) {
            // build a string of Letter, Number and push it to the
            // top of the 'deck'
            char s[2] = { c, char('0' + char(i)) };
            result.emplace_back(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
        }
    }

    // random device delivers true random numbers (on most systems)        
    std::random_device rd {};

    // make a pseudo-random engine, seeded with a real random number
    auto eng = std::default_random_engine(rd());

    // use the engine to shuffle our 'deck' of results
    std::shuffle(std::begin(result), std::end(result), eng);

    return result;
}

// pull the last string off the given 'deck'    
std::string next_candidate(std::vector<std::string>& candidates)
{
    auto result = std::move(candidates.back());
    candidates.pop_back();
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // make a shuffled 'deck' of 'cards' from A1 to I9, but in
    // random order
    std::vector<std::string> candidates = make_candidates();

    // pick the top 5 and print them    
    std::cout << next_candidate(candidates) << std::endl;
    std::cout << next_candidate(candidates) << std::endl;
    std::cout << next_candidate(candidates) << std::endl;
    std::cout << next_candidate(candidates) << std::endl;
    std::cout << next_candidate(candidates) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
F6
F4
I3
F3
G9
```

Comment: Could you comment the code? It's pretty hard to understand it for me.

Comment: @coolguy123 done, as requested. Suggest you read this site: http://en.cppreference.com/

Answer (score 0):

These code blocks are useless. Your function always returns here:

```
string culo =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
{
    int G = rand() % 10;
    int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
    char lOut = letters[G];
    int Max = 5;
    int Min = 0;
    string culo1 =  lOut + to_string(nOut);
    return culo1;  // function returns, no further execution
}
```

Did you mean to check some condition with an `if()` `else if()` cascade to execute these code blocks conditionally?

Comment: No I actually added them to make the code look a bit better.

Comment: @coolguy123 _"to make the code look a bit better"_ So they are useless though. The first `return` statement seen will skip everything that comes afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.